# SQL compilation error: Table '"s3://xxxxxxxxxxxx/output/"' does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are able to load data from `s3://xxxxxxxxxxxx/input/` to Snowflake by using Snow-Pipe.

Code for loading data from S3 bucket to Snowflake:

```
COPY INTO "s3://xxxxxxxxxx/output/" 
FROM @"V_PIPELINE_DB"."V_PIPELINE_SCHEMA"."V_PIPELINE_STAGE"
FILE_FORMAT = ( FORMAT_NAME =  "V_PIPELINE_DB"."V_PIPELINE_SCHEMA"."V_PIPELINE_CSV_FILEFORMAT" )
ON_ERROR = 'continue'
FORCE =TRUE;
```

But we are facing an compiler error while loading from Snowflake to AWS S3 bucket and below is the error.

> SQL compilation error: Table '"s3://xxxxxxxxxxxx/output/"' does not exist

Comment: For a start, you need single quotes, not double, round the s3 bucket name

Comment: @JamesZ when you edited the question you completely changed its meaning - was this deliberate?

Comment: @NickW Where? By removing the duplicate code part? I thought that was supposed to be something different, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you mentioned that the command you attached is loading data from S3 to Snowflake, but that command looks more like the other way around (unloading data from Snowflake to S3). Therefore I'm not sure which query is causing that error.

To get the correct query structure, please refer to the following manuals:

[Loading from S3 to Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-files-directly-from-an-external-location)

[Unloading from Snowflake to S3](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#unloading-data-from-a-table-directly-to-files-in-an-external-location)